# Need to alter regex to allow for special characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, special-characters

I have the following bit of code in my htaccess that will allow a users ID to only be alphanumeric and include underscores and hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've recently imported over 1000 usernames from a social networking platform that allowed usernames to contain special characters, but this new platform I've migrated the usernames into won't.

How could I edit this regex to include the following special characters:

```
[ ] = , ? & @ ~ { } + ' . * ! ™ ` (and spaces).
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everyone seems to be assuming "special character" means "regex metacharacter", but I'm not so sure. There are many people in the world to whom "special character" means punctuation and whitespace characters. I'm pretty sure that's the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([\[\]=,\?&@~\{\}\+'\.*!™`A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Fairly self-explanatory.  Just include all the characters, with escapes if they're regex special characters.

Comment: This is not entirely correct - character classes have a different definition of what are special characters within a class compared to what are special outside of it - some of those \ are redundant.

Comment: Yes, redundant, but still correct.  And easier to move outside the class if needed.